# Can I use the same Jenkins job names on many slaves (i.e. polymorphic)?

Tags: oop, continuous-integration, jenkins, agile

We are POCing a Jenkins "build farm" that consists of 1 master, 2 slaves so far (to be grown down the road).

We use Jenkins mainly to monitor our C++ builds.  Our software targets many different Linux and FreeBSD distributions and releases, together with different compiler suites, so we can see that Jenkins can help boost our efficiency significantly.

But while testing it out, it seems to me that even for the same build job, I have to name jobs differently.  I wonder it's because I have misunderstood Jenkins' usage or it's a current limitation that I have to live with?

To make it concrete, lets say we have 
`m0`, `s0`, and `s1`, where `m0` is the master, `s0` and `s1` are the two slaves.
`j0`, `j1`, ... `jn` as the respective "original" name of our C++ build/test jobs (i.e. when these jobs were ran just on the POC master)

Now, to use `s0` and `s1`, it seems that we must rename our jobs to the following:

```
On m0: m0-j0, m0-j1, ... m0-jn
On s0: s0-j0, s0-j1, ... s0-jn
On s1: s1-j0, s1-j1, ... s1-jn
```

This seems to be quite cumbersome an requirement.  Can we do it in a more Object-Oriented manner - use an attribute somewhere to denote a `j0` should be run on `s0`, and another `j0` should be run on `s1` etc, likewise for other jobs?

Thanks in advance for any hints/tips.

Regards,

-- Zack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need a [Matrix Project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project), which will let you run the same build job in multiple configurations.  The slave to run on is one of the axes that you can use for configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your quick hint! I knew that I must have overlooked something.  Now I am properly oriented.  --Zack